# Java Jung Set Size of Circle to the Width of its String (label)

Tags: java, size, jung, vertices

I started working with java jung. I got a few problems due to the lack of good tutorials. I think i need a few timeto get into it.

Well my problem is:

I created a network with vertices (circles) which are labeled with text (strings).
my problem is to fit the size (width) of the circles to the string.

I wanted to set it dynamically but dont know how to iterate through the vertices.

Comment: tutorial/documentation info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201651/any-good-tutorials-for-jung2

Comment: thx for the link, but it doesnt help me really..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for anyone who has the same question:

```
FontMetrics fm = vv.getFontMetrics(vv.getFont());
int width = fm.stringWidth(i);
```

vv is the VisualizationViewer

Answer (score 1):

For `vv`, a `VizualizationViewer`, you can add a `VertexShapeTransformer`.
The following Scala code is easily translatable into Java.

```
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(
new org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer[String,java.awt.Shape]() {
  def transform(label: String): java.awt.Shape = {
    val width = label.length * 10.0
    val circle = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double(-(width/2), -12.5, width, 25);
    circle // return circle
  }
})
```

Comment: I would be interest in something like that too. But you could upvote anyway :P